# How to compare similarity between two discrete distributions

Tags: statistical-significance, discrete-data

I am trying to compare two temporal distributions. To give an example, consider two factories. For each factory we have a distribution of number of hours taken to produce a product. E.g. 40% of total products were produced in less than an hour, 20% in less than 2 hours but more than 1 and so on and so forth. What is a good way to measure similarity between the two distributions arising from two different factories. I considered using earth movers distance but its a distance metric and not a test.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "similarity"? You can test means, medians, standard deviations, overall location, etc. You could test distance between the curves (perhaps using a permutation test), and probably several other things.

Comment: Thanks Peter,
I am already comparing mean and median of the two distributions. However the distributions are non-standard, not shaped like gaussians, I was wondering if there was some non-parametric way of comparing two distributions.

Comment: There are ways, but it still depends on what you mean by similarity. E.g. Mann Whitney tests if the ranks are similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your statement of the problem, the resulting Earth Movers Distance (EMD) has a formal probabilistic interpretation referred to as the Mallows Distance (among other names). See the reference:

E. Levina and P. Bickel, “The earth mover's distance is the Mallows distance: some insights from statistics,” Computer Vision, 2001. ICCV 2001. Proceedings. Eighth IEEE International Conference on, vol. 2, pp. 251–256 vol. 2, 2001.

With that said, I've never been able to locate an example where it was demonstrated (and would ***greatly*** appreciate a link from someone).

EDIT: I was remiss in not mentioning at least one alternative to EMD for your situation: [The Quadratic-Chi Histogram Distance](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~ofirpele/QC/).

Comment: I know I'm very late to the party, but I just saw this post and want to provide a direct link to the referenced paper: http://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~elevina/EMD.pdf